Problem with calling versioned transactions
Im using this python script to retrieve this version 0 transaction:
import requests

url = 'http://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

payload = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getConfirmedTransaction",
    "params": [
        "5HbX6YFiQJsUhG1RM6YN8KNNY86rEpRJpG9WUWJmirAeiby5B6b6nH5qK43xctCxhecLKCmdKzuA1uFqFrLMfALg",
        {"encoding": "json", "maxSupportedTransactionVersion": 0}
    ]
}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json())
else:
    print("Failed. Status code:", response.status_code)


As you can see im using the maxSupportedVersion: 0 parameter and therefore should be able to call version 0 transactions.
Regardless this script only works on legacy transactions, while im getting this error on version 0 transactions:
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'error': {'code': -32015, 'message': 'Transaction version (0) is not supported by the requesting client. Please try the request again with the following configuration parameter: "maxSupportedTransactionVersion": 0'}, 'id': 1}

Ive tried using different RPCs.
Does anybody have any idea why im still getting this error?

getConfirmedTransaction has been deprecated, so I don't think it supports versioned transactions: https://solana.com/docs/rpc/deprecated/getconfirmedtransaction
Try simply using getTransaction:
payload = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getTransaction",
    "params": [
        "5HbX6YFiQJsUhG1RM6YN8KNNY86rEpRJpG9WUWJmirAeiby5B6b6nH5qK43xctCxhecLKCmdKzuA1uFqFrLMfALg",
        {"encoding": "json", "maxSupportedTransactionVersion": 0}
    ]
}


Yes, my bad forgot about this question, this is the solution.
